# How to display user specific data from firebase as a FlatList in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to reactnative and firebase and i looked for any infomation on this but had no luck in figuring out how to do this. Basically i want to display data from firebase which is specific to the user currently logged in, ive gotten halfway thru but don't understand what to do next. can someone show me what the rest of the code needs to be

Heres my code:

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      uid: ''
    }
  }

  readUserData() {
    currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
    var that = this
    firebase.database().ref(`BorrowedBooks`).child(currentUser.uid).on('value', function (data) {
       console.log(data.val())
    });
  }

  signOut = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))
  }  

  render() {
    this.state = { 
      displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
      uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    }    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>
          Hello, {this.state.displayName}
        </Text>

        <View>
        <FlatList/>
        </View>

        <Button
          color="#3740FE"
          title="Logout"
          onPress={() => this.signOut()}
        />
        <Button
          color="#3740FE"
          title="display books"
          onPress={this.readUserData}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is what my firebase database looks like: [firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcoIP.jpg)

This is the response after console.log: [console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB4MR.jpg)

Comment: are you able to fetch the data?
If you do you should store it in state and then use this state in your flatlist

Comment: i can fetch the data when i console.log but it isnt in the form of an array

Comment: then you should transform it to the shape you want before storing it in state

Comment: thats the issue, i dont quite understand how to do that.. could you maybe show how thats done?

Comment: can you send the response you are getting?

Comment: yup np. i edited the post and attached a image of the terminal at the bottom

Comment: ok you could use Object.keys(data.val()).map(key => data.val([key]))
can you try it?

Comment: where do i put it? i put it  inside readUserData, above console.log but got a error saying.. DataSnapshot.val failed: was called with 1 argument. expects none.

Comment: take a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-oskar-vmmdx?file=/src/App.js it is far from complete but will give you an idea.
You need to learn how to use firebase, flastlist, state. It's good that you are aiming far but this is not a stack overflow question. you need a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the data in an array before you can display it in FlatList

```
readUserData() {
    currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
    var that = this
    firebase.database().ref(`BorrowedBooks`).child(currentUser.uid).on('value', function (data) {
       //console.log(data.val())
      let DATA = [];
      if(data.exists()){
        KEY = Object.keys(data.val());

        KEY.forEach( (key_id) => {
          let a = snapshot.val()[key_id];
          a.key = key_id;
          DATA.push(a);

        })
      that.setState({userData: DATA})

    });
  }
```

then you can display it in flatlist

```
<FlatList 
  data = {this.state.userData}
  renderItem ={({item}) =>
  //render Items here
  }
 />
```